# Initialize array of strings

Tags: c, initialization

What is the right way to initialize `char**` ?
I get coverity error -  Uninitialized pointer read (UNINIT) when trying:

```
char **values = NULL;
```

or

```
char **values = { NULL };
```

Comment: That's fine for initializing them to be no strings at all; you will still need to point them somewhere valid before you use them (using malloc or similar).

Comment: Linux r-mgtswh-130 2.6.18-348.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jan 8 17:53:53 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This compiles using gcc. Are you saying this doesn't compile for you, or that you're getting an error when you run your program?

Comment: `char ** values` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, nothing more. `values` is no array of "strings".

Comment: is there a problem to do `char *values[] =` to allocate the array on stack?

Answer (score 79):

This example program illustrates initialization of an array of C strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char * array[] = {
    "First entry",
    "Second entry",
    "Third entry",
};

#define n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *))

int main ()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        printf ("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out the following:

```
0: First entry
1: Second entry
2: Third entry
```

Comment: Hi, it works! But i have a question, why i have to use #define n_array here? I have tried with:  int  n_array, and my app crashes, i'm new to C and dont understand this behavior - #define instead of simple variable int. Thanks.

Comment: @teMkaa Using `#define` is just a question of style; personally I wouldn't have done it. Within the `main` function you could easily define another int variable and assign it to `sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *)`.

Answer (score 16):

Its fine to just do `char **strings;`, `char **strings = NULL`, or `char **strings = {NULL}`

but to initialize it you'd have to use malloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    // allocate space for 5 pointers to strings
    char **strings = (char**)malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
    int i = 0;
    //allocate space for each string
    // here allocate 50 bytes, which is more than enough for the strings
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        strings[i] = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    }
    //assign them all something
    sprintf(strings[0], "bird goes tweet");
    sprintf(strings[1], "mouse goes squeak");
    sprintf(strings[2], "cow goes moo");
    sprintf(strings[3], "frog goes croak");
    sprintf(strings[4], "what does the fox say?");
    // Print it out
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Line #%d(length: %lu): %s\n", i, strlen(strings[i]),strings[i]);
    } 
    //Free each string
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        free(strings[i]);
    }
    //finally release the first string
    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (I'd expext some c-grammar nazzi commenting about the typecast before malloc)

Comment: I guess it's just habit from writing C++ and having to do that

Comment: Thank you so much. It help me a lot.

Answer (score 11):

There is no right way, but you can initialize an array of literals:

```
char **values = (char *[]){"a", "b", "c"};
```

or you can allocate each and initialize it:

```
char **values = malloc(sizeof(char*) * s);
for(...)
{
    values[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * l);
    //or
    values[i] = "hello";
}
```

Comment: using `malloc()` is the way to go

Comment: I get compiler error `taking address of temporary array` when trying to compile `char **values = (char *[]){"a", "b", "c"};` ...
`char *values[] = {"a", "b", "c"};` works however

Comment: I googled "c inline array of strings" and you line with `(char *[]){"a", "b", "c"}` matches my request ideally.